# Meaning of "unravel" in "threatens to further unravel Africa’s second-most populous country"

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, american-english

The text is:

> An ethnically motivated campaign largely targeting Tigrayans threatens to further **unravel** Africa’s second-most populous country a year into civil war.

If the definition of "unravel" in the text is something like "investigate and solve" or "explain", then the gist of the text is a little weird to me. Why would investigating or explaining a country be a threat?

Comment: You are misreading unravel.  *The threat** is the "ethnically motivated campaign". unravel means: to come apart or take apart, it does not mean investigate or solve. They unraveled the mystery.=They took the mystery apart.

Answer (score 6):

If one definition doesn't make sense, then it's likely that [the other one](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/unravel) does:

> to take apart; undo; destroy (a plan, agreement, or arrangement).

The implication being that the country is falling apart, and the campaign threatens to further that process.